# Is there a way to use a custom stores?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and trying to build web api with `Openiddict` for security, what I'm looking for is a way to implement my own `UserStore` and other stores and use them ?
Is there an easy sample or example to follow ?
I tried to implement `IUserStore` and add it to `IServiceCollection` and used `AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()`.

When I'm trying to execute `identityUserManager.CreateAsync(user,..)` I'm getting the following error.

> The entity type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin'
>   requires a primary key to be defined

I think the user class I'm creating and because it's inheriting from `IdentityUser` which is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`, causing this problem, now I didn't find another `IdentityUser` in another name space two inherit from, isn't there any ?

Comment: You can use AddUserStore and AddRoleStore in your startup.cs

Comment: @Béranger I used them, but started to get error about `UserLogin` which doesn't have extension method, to be used to be add with

Comment: if you are not going to use the provided EFCore implementation of the Stores then you should remove the dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore from your project.json to make sure you are not still using some bits of it like ApplicationUser in the default project template inherits from IdentityUser which is an EFCore implementation, you'll need to define your own user class.

Comment: @JoeAudette and this custom class doesn't need to inherit from `IUser` like in ASP.NET 4.5 ?

Comment: doesn't have to inherit from anything, if you are looking for code ideas, I have implemented custom stores for multi tenant identity https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe